# Mapbox Store locator, number items on list and match numbers as markers on the map

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am following the example in this tutorial: https://www.mapbox.com/help/geocode-and-sort-stores/

I am trying to give the stores a number (or letter) on the list and have the same number appear as a marker on the map.

Could not find much about how to do this on mapbox documentation. Would really appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the url for icon as per your require ment

```js
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
    // create a DOM element for the marker
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';
    el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://placekitten.com/g/' + marker.properties.iconSize.join('/') + '/)';
    el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
    el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';

    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.alert(marker.properties.message);
    });

    // add marker to map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
        .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
        .addTo(map);
});
```